# Click event doesn't fire on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-8, winjs, windows-8.1

I am building a Windows 8.1 Store application with WinJS. When the user queries some search results show up in a `<p class="searchresults">content</p>` tag.

I'd like to add an event handler to the `.searchresults` class. I've done the following:

```
$('.searchresults').on('click', function() {
console.log("clicked");
});
```

I've tried even without `.on()`

```
$('.searchresults').click(function() {
console.log("clicked");
});
```

However the event never gets fired. I've set up a breakpoint, so I can see when it fires - but that never happens

I've tried to add an event handler via the WinJS way:

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(document.getElementsByClassName("searchresults"), 'click', myfunc);
```

Without success.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will guess that you are creating the `<p class="searchresults">content</p>` object AFTER you try to install the event handler (a common problem with dynamic content).  That will not work with normal event handling because the DOM object does not exist when you try to add the event handler to it.

If this is the case, then you need to use delegated event handling like this:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.searchresults', function() {
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

This will allow you to dynamically create the searchresults content at any time and the event handler will still fire via event delegation (events propagate up to their parents).

---

You haven't shown the HTML around the search results content, but the most optimal way to do this is to select the closest static parent to the search results (a parent that is not dynamically created and already exists at the time you attach the event handler) and attach the event to that:

```
$(closest static parent selector).on('click', '.searchresults', function() {
    console.log("clicked");
});
```